# Get messages since beginning using IMAP in node

Tags: node.js, email, meteor, imap, node-imap

I am using mail-listener package of npm to get all inbox messages since a specific date.

Here is my code for getting inbox messages,

```
'listener':function(credit,userid = this.userId,date = (new Date()).toString()){
        if(credit.port === "143" || credit.port === "993") {
            let mailListener2 = new MailListener({
                username: credit.user,
                password: credit.password,
                host: credit.host,
                port: credit.port, // imap port
                tls: (credit.port === "993"),
                connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
                authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
                debug: null, // Or your custom function with only one incoming argument. Default: null
                tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
                mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
                searchFilter: [["SINCE", date]],
                markSeen: false, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
                fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
                //mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
                attachments: false, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
                attachmentOptions: {directory: "/data/attachments/"} // specify a download directory for attachments
            });

            mailListener2.on("server:connected", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
                console.log("imapConnected");
            }));

            mailListener2.on("server:disconnected", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
                console.log("imapDisconnected");
            }));

            mailListener2.on("error", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
                console.log("error listener", err);
            }));
            mailListener2.on("mail", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (mail) {
                console.log("receive message");
            }));

            mailListener2.start();
        }else if(credit.port === "587" || credit.port === "465"){
            if not imap ....
        }
        return true;
    },
```

I would like to allow my user to just select option if start on beginning or in a specific date. So my problem here is,I don't know how to get all inbox messages from the beginning. How can I do that?

Do I need to use SINCE also?

Answer (score 0):

-If you want to get all inbox messages you can just put the option like this: searchFilter: ['UNSEEN'].

-If you want to get all messages from a specific date you can put the option like this (using moment lib): searchFilter: ['UNSEEN', ['SINCE', moment(DATE_USER).format('ll')]],